# Visual Studio 2013 debugger shows old (deleted) code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I can't debug in Visual Studio 2013 as every time I attempt to do so, the debugger runs old code that's been deleted for weeks. I've tried all the usual things - deleting binaries, rebuilding solution, etc. - but nothing seems to make VS see the latest version of the code so that I can set breakpoints and debug.

Comment: How does the debugger step into deleted code? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It doesn't. I can't set a breakpoint or step into code as the debugger is running some older binaries it's cached some place.

Comment: CTRL+F5 in IE fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your project
2. Delete the temp asp.net folder
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/08/11/clearing-out-temporary-asp-net-files.aspx
3. Look where your symbolic debug information file is located (.pdb) and you can do this through Debug->Windows->Modules

Find your module and look under "Symbol Status" and "Symbol File" to see where Visual Studio is finding your .pdb file at. This file contains binary to source information so you can debug. Typically when you see what you've described its looking at an old one (or can't find one at all and then you get the question marks that show up on your breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was building a web application and the debugger was running on Chrome, the issue was the temp files held by Chrome.
I went to Chrome's *"Clear browsing data"* page (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData) and deleted the *"cached images and files"*.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Go to: DEBUG -> options and settings -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run Select: "Do not launch"

[image: Select "Do not launch]

It doesnt seem logical for me, but the default parameter here is to launch the old build...not sure how this should help if I see the last working solution but not the code...nevertheless, it worked for me. Hope it works for you as well.